# Flutter : sending data across multiple screens

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 3 Widget `MyApp Widget` ,`Home Widget`, and `Sliver Appbar Widget`, It's connected to each other. Example **MyApp Widget** -> **Home Widget** -> **SliverAppbar Widget**.

My question is , how to Passing data from **My App Widget** directly to **SliverAppBar Widget** ?

[image]

I found what i think it's can solve my case that is [Inherited Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html). But i confused to understading to use this widget.

I already try using Inherited Widget as documentation like this :

### MyApp Widget

```
class SettingsApp extends InheritedWidget {
  SettingsApp({Key key, this.isDarkMode = false, Widget child})
      : super(key: key, child: child);

  final bool isDarkMode;

  static SettingsApp of(BuildContext context) {
    return (context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<SettingsApp>());
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(SettingsApp oldWidget) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

### SliverAppBar Widget

```
class SliverAppBarCustom extends StatelessWidget {
  final Box detbBox = Hive.box("debt_box");
  final UserModelHive userModelHive = Hive.box("user_box").get("userSession");
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isDarkMode =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<SettingsApp>().isDarkMode;
    print(isDarkMode.toString());
    var mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    var textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
     return Text(isDarkMode.toString());
  }
}
```

But i get this error :

### Log

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building SliverAppBarCustom(dirty):
The getter 'isDarkMode' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isDarkMode
```

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt

Comment: I dont want using Provider, because i already using `Hive` Package.

Comment: I can't see why you couldn't use Provider along with Hive, Provider has nothing to to with database storage, it is a state management pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ScopedModel`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class SettingsModel extends Model {
  bool _isDarkMode;

  SettingsModel({bool isDarkMode}) : _isDarkMode = isDarkMode ?? false;

  bool get isDarkModel => _isDarkMode;

  set isDarkModel(bool value) {
    _isDarkMode = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void switchTheme() {
    _isDarkMode = !_isDarkMode;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  static SettingsModel of(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel.of<SettingsModel>(context);
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel<SettingsModel>(
      model: SettingsModel(isDarkMode: true),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: InitPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InitPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Init Page")),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ScopedModelDescendant<SettingsModel>(
              builder: (context, child, model) {
                return Text('Is Dark Mode: ${model.isDarkModel}');
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Next Page"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SecondPage(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Page"),
      ),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ScopedModelDescendant<SettingsModel>(
              builder: (context, child, model) {
                return Text('Is Dark Mode: ${model.isDarkModel}');
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Switch Theme"),
              onPressed: SettingsModel.of(context).switchTheme,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Important:** You should not change `_isDarkModel` without `notifyListeners()`. If you do UI may not update.

Comment: It's same thing if i passing data from bottom to above ? something like **SliverAppBar Widget** -> **MyApp Widget** ?

Comment: `InheritedWidget` is immutable. You cannot reassign values to their instance variable. Its used to effectively pass the data down to the widget tree.

Comment: You can use `ScopedModel` which is implemented based on this `InheritedWidget` concept and allows you to change data as well.

Comment: I update my Image for more detail, My case i passed data to **SliverAppBar Widget** and changed it to `isDarkMode=true` and Passing it again to **MyApp Widget**. It's can solved with `ScopedModel` ?

Comment: @ZeffryReynando yes. I updated the code. Sorry, add `@name` while commenting to notify that person